# SPServices Cascade Dropdown ListItem Threshold

Tags: spservices, list-view-threshold, cascading

I am using the `SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns` function. The relationship list just recently went over the 5,000 listitem threshold limit. I now get this error where my fields used to be:

> This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that currently exceeds the List View Threshold defined by the administrator (5000). To add items to the current list, please ask the list owner to remove this column.

Is there something that I can add to my SPServices function or around it that can work around the list item threshold?

Comment: You could google Change Listview Threshold and it will return you tons of links of how to do this, many even pointing to this site

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do, but to maybe have your IT team lift the restriction on that particular list (or the lookup list for the column).

From the creator of SPServices, there is this post: http://sympmarc.com/2014/02/18/getting-around-sharepoints-threshold-limits-for-large-reference-lists/

Also, on the SPServices forums there is a post where the solution to lift the threshold is shown. It was provided by MS support: https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/280642